# How do I upgrade my Ubuntu server from one LTS version to another? Is this safe?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, system-installation, lts, do-release-upgrade

I like to keep all my servers running only the most stable versions of any operating system, so obviously I only run the LTS versions of Ubuntu.

I currently have a few servers running Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. I'd like to upgrade them to 14.04. Is it safe to jump versions like that, and how can this be done?

Comment: Yes you can upgrade from LTS to LTS, when the first point release (14.04.1) around july is aviable you can safetly upgrade your server.

Comment: Was this available for previous LTS releases? if so, can you post the command to do so. also, can you make this a response so i can mark this as an answer? :)

Comment: Yes it was. Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#From_10.04_to_12.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally recommended (read safer) that users of Ubuntu LTS wait until the first point release, due in July, before upgrading.

To upgrade from Ubuntu LTS on a server system (and Desktop too) before then, follow the steps listed below:

Ensure you're up to date with latest updates for Ubuntu.

[Backup!](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) **Don't skip this step.** Unexpected things can happen during an upgrade and you'll want to be prepared in case they do!

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install `update-manager-core` if it is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and if necessary set `Prompt=lts`. Note: The minimum contents of `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` should be:

```
[DEFAULT]

Prompt=lts
```

Launch the upgrade tool:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the on-screen instructions.

Slightly modified from Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#From_10.04_to_12.04

For more on do-release-upgrade and some handy options, see [the man page.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html)

Comment: Is this still compatible answer for 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade when 17.04, 17.10 have already been published? ie for this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020218/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-specific-version

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Short answer is yes. The publishing  of what I like to call STS (short term support) releases should have no bearing whatsoever on LTS to LTS upgrades